# Is it possible to always mount a config map to all pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to follow something similar to the Istio injection model where Istio is able to run a mutating admission webhook in order to auto inject their sidecar.

We would like to do something similar, but with some config maps.  We have a need to mount config maps to all new pods in a given namespace, always mounted at the same path.  Is it possible to create a mutating admission webhook that will allow me to mount this config map at the known path while admitting new pods?

docs to mutating webhooks: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be entirely possible and is, in fact, an aligned use-case for a custom mutating admission webhook. Unfortunately, the official documentation on actually implementing them is somewhat sparse.

[This is the most useful reference material](https://github.com/morvencao/kube-mutating-webhook-tutorial) I found when I was working on [this mutating admission webhook](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/mutating-trace-admission-controller).

The general process is as follows:

1. Generate and deploy certificates [as demonstrated here](https://github.com/morvencao/kube-mutating-webhook-tutorial#deploy)
2. Deploy [MutatingWebhookConfiguration](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/mutating-trace-admission-controller/blob/master/deploy/base/mutatingwebhook.yaml) to your cluster. This configuration allows us to tell the API server where to send the `AdmissionReview` objects. This is also where you should specify which operations on which API resources in which namespaces you want to target.
3. Write the actual webhook server, which should accept `AdmissionReview` objects at the specified endpoint (`/mutate` is the convention) and return `AdmissionResponse` objects with the mutated object, [as is shown here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/mutating-trace-admission-controller/blob/589ff8723d1bc632c0ba2bb55313986db126d750/webhook.go#L85) (note: in the linked example, I added an annotation to incoming pods that fit a certain criteria, while your application would add a field for the `ConfigMap`)
4. Deploy the webhook server and expose it using normal methods (`Deployment` and `Service`, or whatever fits your use case). Make sure it's accessible at the location you specified in the configuration for the `MutatingWebhookConfiguration`

Hope this was enough information! Let me know if I left anything too vague / was unclear.